# Why the data cut(incomplete) when inserting text in Lvarchar field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql, informix

I try to insert text data in a field of type `Lvarchar (informix database)`

but when i check the inserted data i find it 's not complete i don't know why ?!

MY original data (should be inserted)is formatted like this :

```
<p dir="LTR" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt; text-align: right;"><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الأسعار</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">للعضو</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">والأقارب</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">من</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الدرجة</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الأولي</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">بحد</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">أقصى</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong></p>
<p dir="LTR" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt; text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot; </span><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">عدم</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">تمتع</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">العضو</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">بأي</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">دعم</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">من</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">الصندوق</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">لرحلات</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">العمرة</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">خلال</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">الثلاث</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">سنوات</span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">الماضية</span></p>
<p dir="LTR" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt; text-align: right;"><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">المستندات</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">المطلوبة</span></p>
<p dir="LTR" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt 36pt; text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-size: 7pt; font-family: Times New Roman; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot; </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">جواز</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">سفر</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">صالح</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">لمدة</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> 6 </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">أشهر</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">من</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">تاريخ</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">السفر</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">.</span></p>
<p dir="LTR" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt 36pt; text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-size: 7pt; font-family: Times New Roman; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot; </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">صورة</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">بطاقة</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">الرقم</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">القومي</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">في</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">حالة</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">الجوا</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">ا</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">زت</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;"> </span><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">القديمة</span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">.</span></p>
<p dir="LTR"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Symbol;">&middot; </span><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">طريقة</span></strong><strong><span style="font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">السداد</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">: </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">نقدي</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">أو</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">تقسيط</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> )</span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">مقدم</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">بحد</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">إدني</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> 45 % </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">والباقي</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">علي</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">أقساط</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">بحد</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">أقصي</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> 44 </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">شهر</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">(</span></strong><span dir="RTL"><br />
<br />
</span><strong>3. Forced format stripping on Paste</strong></p>
<p dir="LTR">Developers can now enforce content formatting using the new <strong>StripFormattingOptions</strong> property. As a result, format stripping will be applied to all pasted content, with the following options: None, MSWord (retains fonts and sizes), MSWordNoFonts, MSWordRemoveAll, Css, Font, Span, All.</p>
<p dir="LTR"><strong>4. Word Content in Clipboard Interception</strong></p>
<p dir="LTR"><span style="color: #595959;">In case the user is trying to paste Word content with the regular Paste button or Ctrl+V, a dialog will prompt whether the Word markup should be cleaned. If the Clipboard content does not come from Word, the dialog will not be shown.</span></p>
<p dir="LTR"><strong>5. Strip Word-formatting after paste</strong></p>
<p dir="LTR">As an alternative to the "Paste from Word" tool (item 1) you may paste the formatted content first and then strip it using the "Format Stripper" tool.<br />
<br />
<br />
</p>
<p dir="RTL"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial;">- </span></strong><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman,serif;">هو برنامج يستخدم في إدخال أكبر قد ممكن من النصوص باللغتين العربية والإنجليزية ، بأشكال وتنسيقات مختلفة وبالتالي فهو أفضل برامج الكمبيوتر التي تستخدم لإعداد المكاتبات الرسمية ،كما يستخدم في إدخال العديد من الصور والأشكال التلقائية ، التي تمكن من إعداد الهياكل والمخططات ، كما يستخدم في إعداد الجداول والمخططات البيانية بالأشكال المختلفة .</span></strong><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial;"> <br />
</span></strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">ثانياً : كيفية فتح البرنامج . <br />
================<br />
-نقوم بالضغط على أيقونة </span><span dir="LTR">start</span><span style="font-family: Arial;"> لعرض القائمة الخاصة بها ثم نضع مؤشر الفأرة فوق كلمة برامج ( </span><span dir="LTR">programs</span><span style="font-family: Arial;"> (<br />
- ستظهر لنا قائمة فرعية نختار كلمة (</span><span dir="LTR">word (Microsoft</span><span style="font-family: Arial;"><br />
الدرس الثاني : <br />
========<br />
<em>تحويل واجهة برنامج ا لورد </em></span><em><span dir="LTR">word</span></em><span style="font-family: Arial;"> <br />
==================== <br />
<strong><span style="color: #5f497a;">1- نضغط على زر </span></strong></span><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">start</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> أبدأ من شريط المهام تظهر لنا قائمة . <br />
2- نختار منها أمر </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">programs</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> البرامج تظهر قائمة فرعية . <br />
3- نختار منها أمر </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">Microsoft office tools</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> تظهر لنا قائمة فرعية أخرى <br />
4- نختار منها أمر </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">Microsoft office language settings</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> <br />
5- نختار منه </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">Arabic</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> أو نختار </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">English</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> ثم نقوم بالضغط على زر </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">yes</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> <br />
وبهذه ا لعملية تحول جميع البرامج لمجموعة </span></strong><strong><span dir="LTR" style="color: #5f497a;">Office</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #5f497a; font-family: Arial;"> كلها في وقت واحد</span></strong></p>
```

---

The only inserted part is :

```
<p dir="LTR" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt; text-align: right;"><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الأسعار</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">للعضو</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">والأقارب</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">من</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الدرجة</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">الأولي</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">بحد</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong><strong><span dir="RTL" style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;">أقصى</span></strong><strong><span style="color: #c0504d; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,Bold;"> </span></strong></p>
<p dir="LTR" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt; text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Symbol;">&m
```

---

The method i used to insert :

```
cmdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO dr66req(req_ser, req_year, req_date, req_emp_type, req_emp_num, req_emp_name, person_type,person_num,person_name,about_person,other_description,main_code , year,req_desc, login_num , req_title,request_file) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?) ");
                    using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
                    {
                        myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_ser", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_year", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_date", IfxType.Date);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_emp_type", IfxType.SmallInt);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_emp_num", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_emp_name", IfxType.NVarChar);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("person_type", IfxType.SmallInt);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("person_num", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("person_name", IfxType.NVarChar);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("about_person", IfxType.NChar);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("other_description", IfxType.NChar);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("main_code", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("year", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_desc", IfxType.LVarChar, 32739);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("login_num", IfxType.Integer);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("req_title", IfxType.NVarChar);
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("request_file", IfxType.Byte);

                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                        }

                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = ((object)MaxFollowSerial) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)obj.RequestYear) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)obj.RequestDate) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[3].Value = ((object)obj.RequestEmpType) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[4].Value = ((object)obj.RequestEmpNum) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[5].Value = ((object)obj.RequestEmpName.TrimEnd()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[6].Value = ((object)obj.PersonType) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[7].Value = ((object)obj.PersonNum) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[8].Value = ((object)obj.PersonName.Trim()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[9].Value = ((object)obj.AboutPerson.Trim()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[10].Value = ((object)obj.OtherDescription.Trim()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[11].Value = ((object)obj.MainCode) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[12].Value = ((object)obj.Year) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[13].Value = ((object)obj.RequestDescription.TrimEnd()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[14].Value = ((object)obj.LoginNum) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[15].Value = ((object)obj.Title.Trim()) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[16].Value = ((object)obj.Request_file) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        affectedRow = myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

Comment: Have you gave size for your field when creating table? if you not specify size for LVARCHAR then it will hold  2 kilobytes (2048 bytes) only

Comment: @Damith : Then how to set the size of this field ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to give size of the `LVarChar` column when you creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE dr66req
   (
   req_ser     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   req_desc    LVarChar(32739),


);
```

Comment: If the table has data and i wanna to change the size of this field only,how to do that ?

Comment: try to alter table column size if failed backup your table data and drop the table and create new one with changes and insert previous data

Comment: You better ask question [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) if you not familier with informix

Comment: `The operation causes a row size to exceed the allowable limit 32739`

Comment: @just_name In case of issue with your input please test with large text (like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.....") with character count arround 30000, if it worked you don't need to change the size of column

Comment: ALTER TABLE dr66req  MODIFY (req_desc LVARCHAR(30700));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31485/discussion-between-damith-and-just-name)